# Fields closed up to degree $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclotomic-fields

Are there fields that are not algebraically closed fields but such that any quadratic polynomial has a root?

Suppose now $n$ is a fixed natural number, $n\geq 2$. Is there a field $K_n$ such that every polinomial of degree $\leq n$ with coefficients in $K_n$ has a root in $K_n$, but $K_n$ is not algebraically closed?

---

I was thinking that perhaps a tower of algebraic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ might work, but then I realized that in order to be "quadratically closed" I might have to close under all extensions of degree $2^k$ for some $k$.

Is $K_2=\bigcup \left\{\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]: [\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=2^k\text{  for some $k$}\right\}$ going to work as a field that is quadratically closed but not algebraically closed?

Comment: @Crostul In the link of the duplicate is not clear to me if my approach works or if it does not. Do you have a hint?

Comment: To know if your approach works, we need to know what it is! How do you plan to show that union is a field and, if it is, how do you know it is not algebraically closed?

Comment: Let $P$ be a finite set of prime numbers. Then $$\{ \alpha | [\Bbb{Q}(\alpha ) : \Bbb{Q}] \mbox{ is a product of primes } \in P \}$$ is a not algebraically closed field. Now take $P= \{ 2,3,5,7\}$ (for example).

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I was thinking $K_2$ as defined was going to be a field that was "quadratically closed" but not algebraically closed. (Of course, $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$). If so, then Crostul's comment would be the obvious generalization of the idea.

Comment: @Crostul The part that I do not see very clear is to show that $K_2$ is a field. I know it suffices to show that it is closed under products and sums, but I don't see easy how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The probably must famous example are the *constructable numbers*, i.e. the lengths that can be constructed using a straight-edge, a compass, and an already drawn line segment of length $1$. You can add, subtract, multiply, divide and solve any quadratic equation with constructions, as long as the coefficients are constructible, but you cannot take cube roots.

For the general situation, let $n\in \Bbb N$, and let $K = K_0$ be a field not of characteristic $n$. Then, let $K_1 \subseteq \overline K$ be the smallest subfield containing $K$ and the roots of all polynomials of degree $n$ with coefficients in $K$. Next, define $K_2\subseteq \overline K$ be the smallest subfield containing $K_1$ and the roots of all degree-$n$ polynomials with coefficients in $K_1$.

Keep going like that, and you will get a chain $K= K_0\subseteq K_1\subseteq\cdots$ of fields. The union $K_\omega$ of all these fields is still a field, and it will contain the zeroes of any $n$-th degree polynomial with coefficients in $K_\omega$. The proof of these two statements both revolve around the same fact: For any given addition, subtraction, multiplication, division and polynomial, there are only finitely many numbers involved, so the problem is entirely contained in some $K_i$ for a finite $i \in \Bbb N$.

Note that $K_\omega$ may be algebraically closed, even though $K$ isn't. For a simple example, set $K = \Bbb R$ and $n = 2$. In that case $K_1 = K_2 = \cdots = \Bbb C$. However, in the case of, for instance, $K = \Bbb Q$, this process cannot end in $\overline {\Bbb Q}$, since that would mean that $\sqrt[n+1]2 \in K_\omega$, which again means that there is an $i\in \Bbb N$ such that $\sqrt[n+1]2 \in K_i$. How could that have gotten there?

The answer is, of course, that it couldn't. Over $\overline{\Bbb Q}$, all $n$-th degree factors of $x^{n+1} - 2$ have $\sqrt[n+1]2$ (and powers thereof, with some complex $(n+1)$-th roots of $1$ and $-1$ thrown into the mix) as coefficients, which means that there cannot ever be a *smallest* $i$ for which $\sqrt[n+1]2\in K_i$.

Comment: It's a good example, but unfortunately it does not answer the more general question.

Comment: @Wore I added an answer for general degrees.

Comment: Great!, thanks for taking the time of writing this answer up.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, such a quadratically closed field field exists.
Start with an arbitrary field $K=K_0$ of characteristic $\neq 2$ and adjoin all square roots of elements of $K$.
In other words consider the splitting field of the family ($X^2-q)_{q\in K}$ and obtain the field $K_1=K(\sqrt q\vert q\in K)=K(\sqrt K)$.
Define inductively $K_{n+1}=K_n(\sqrt K_n)$ and obtain an increasing sequence of fields $$K=K_0\subset\cdots \subset K_n\subset\cdots$$ 
The union $K_\text{quad}=\cup_{n=0}^\infty K_n$ is a field (like all increasing union of fields) closed under extraction of square roots but $K_\text{quad}$  is not algebraically closed in general: indeed any element of $K_\text{quad}$ has degree $2^n$ for some $n$ .

Comment: It is a good example, but I am afraid it does not answer the more general question. Also another question, are you using the quadratic formula to ensure that $K$ is "quadratically closed"? It is clear that all square roots will be included in $K$, but for more general quadratic polynomials I only can think about the quadratic formula to ensure that they will have roots in $K$.

Comment: @Wore The quadratic formula consists of addition, subtraction, multiplication, division and a single square root. So if the square root of any element is in our field, then the quadratic formula can always be resolved in our field.

Comment: @Arthur I know. That's why I said it was the only way I see to ensure every quadratic polynomial will have roots in $K$. However, such an argument will fail for higher degrees, hence I wanted to know if Georges was thinking about something else that can work more generally.